# Vector calculus trouble in Hamilton's equations / particle in E.M.field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, hamiltonian-formalism, vector-fields

As part of applying Hamilton's equations to a particle in
an electromagnetic field, one step is to take

$\dot{\mathbf{p}} = - \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{r}}
= -\nabla H = - \nabla [\dfrac{1}{2m} (\mathbf{p} - \dfrac{q}{c}\mathbf{A})
\cdot (\mathbf{p} - \dfrac{q}{c}\mathbf{A}) + q\phi]$

They arrive at

$\dot{\mathbf{p}} = \dfrac{1}{m} \nabla [(\mathbf{p} - \dfrac{q}{c}\mathbf{A})
\cdot (\dfrac{q}{c}\mathbf{A})] - q \nabla \phi$

I apply the vector calculus identity

$\dfrac{1}{2} \nabla (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{A})
= (\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{A}
+ \mathbf{A} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{A})$

and can't get what they get.  Please help.

(One thing they say:  "$\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ are
independent phase space variables in Hamilton's approach, so
$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{p} = 0$.  Using  $\nabla (\mathbf{p}
\cdot \mathbf{p}) = 0$..")

Comment: I would alway avoid using vector notation in these kinds of problems. It is much more helpful to work with indices, and employing the $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{mnk}=\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}$ formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ - \vec\nabla [\dfrac{1}{2m} (\vec p - \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A)
\cdot (\vec p- \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A) + q\phi]=$

$ - \vec\nabla [\dfrac{1}{2m} (\vec p - \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A)
\cdot (\vec p- \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A)]  -q\vec\nabla\phi=$

$ \vec\nabla\left[ \frac{-\vec p\cdot\vec p +2 \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A
\cdot \vec p- \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A\cdot\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A }{2m}\right]-q\vec\nabla\phi=$

$ \vec\nabla\left[ \frac{2 \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A
\cdot \vec p- \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A\cdot\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A }{2m} \right]-q\vec\nabla\phi=$

$ \vec\nabla \left[\frac{\vec p \cdot \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A- \dfrac{q}{2c}\vec A\cdot\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A }{m}\right] -q\vec\nabla\phi=$

$ \vec\nabla \left[\frac{ \left( \vec p- \dfrac{q}{2c}\vec A\right)\cdot\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A }{m}\right] -q\vec\nabla\phi=$

$ \vec\nabla \left[\frac{1}{m} \left( \vec p- \dfrac{q}{2c}\vec A\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A \right)\right] -q\vec\nabla\phi.$

Do not apply the vector calculus identity

$\dfrac{1}{2} \vec\nabla (\vec {A} \cdot \vec{A})
= (\vec{A} \cdot \vec\nabla)\vec {A}
+ \vec{A} \times (\vec\nabla \times \vec{A}),$

since you want the final answer to have a gradient in it. Now, all I've used is linearity of the gradient, expanding out the inner product, and eliminating the term you said was zero. So if you accept those, that is what you get. Normally for homework I wouldn't show all the steps, but since you aren't getting the answer you were hoping for I wanted you to see how close it comes.

> Okay, so you are allowed to use chain rule like this?$\nabla [\dfrac{1}{2m}(\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A}) \cdot
>                      (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})]
>  - q \nabla \phi$
>   $= \dfrac{1}{2m} \nabla [(\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})^2]
>  - q \nabla \phi$
>   $=
> \dfrac{1}{2m} [2 (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})
> [\nabla \cdot (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})]]
>  - q \nabla \phi$   (chain rule)
>   $=\dfrac{1}{2m} [2 (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})
> [(\nabla \cdot \vec{p}) - (\nabla \cdot (\dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A}))]]
>  - q \nabla \phi$
>   $= \dfrac{1}{2m} [2 (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})
> [0 - (\nabla \cdot (\dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A}))]]
>  - q \nabla \phi$   (since they said $\nabla \cdot \vec{p} = 0$)
>
> It seems too easy, like cheating,
>   when you look at if you had tried
>   to use  $\dfrac{1}{2} \nabla (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{A})
> = (\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{A}
> + \mathbf{A} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{A})$  instead.

I don't know why you would just make up a new (and wrong) vector identity. If you are going to *evaluate* the gradient, then *do* use the calculus identity $\dfrac{1}{2} \vec\nabla (\vec {A} \cdot \vec{A})
= (\vec{A} \cdot \vec\nabla)\vec {A}
+ \vec{A} \times (\vec\nabla \times \vec{A}),$
This is useful If you are trying to *evaluate* the gradient. Just do *not* use it to show a result that still has the gradient in it because that calculus identity removes all the gradients, so it isn't going to get you from one line with a gradient to another line that also has a gradient.

You can also remove all the vectors by doing some sums. If $\partial_1=\partial/\partial x,$ $\partial_2=\partial/\partial y,$ $\partial_3=\partial/\partial z$ and writing $\vec p=p^1\hat x+p^2\hat y+p^3\hat z$ and $\vec A=A^1\hat x+A^2\hat y+A^3\hat z$ with $\vec e_1=\hat x,$ $\vec e_2=\hat y,$ and $\vec e_3=\hat z,$ then the line we get (with the 1/2) evaluates like:

$ \left[\vec\nabla \left[\frac{1}{m} \left( \vec p- \dfrac{q}{2c}\vec A\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A \right)\right] -q\vec\nabla\phi\right]\cdot \hat e_i=$

$ \partial_i\left[\frac{1}{m} \left( \vec p- \dfrac{q}{2c}\vec A\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A \right)\right] -q\partial_i\phi=$

$ \partial_i\left[\frac{1}{m} \sum_j\left( p^j- \dfrac{q}{2c} A^j\right)\left(\dfrac{q}{c} A^j \right)\right] -q\partial_i\phi=$

$\frac{1}{m} \sum_j \partial_i\left[\left( p^j- \dfrac{q}{2c} A^j\right)\left(\dfrac{q}{c} A^j \right)\right] -q\partial_i\phi$ at which point it is just a product rule and a simplification away.

It is even easier if you start with the original equation, get rid of the vectors and then use the chain rule for scalars, i.e.

$ \left[\vec\nabla \left[\frac{-1}{2m} \left( \vec p- \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A\right)\cdot\left(\vec p-\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A \right)\right] -q\vec\nabla\phi\right]\cdot \hat e_i=$

$ \partial_i\left[\frac{-1}{2m} \left( \vec p- \dfrac{q}{c}\vec A\right)\cdot\left(\vec p-\dfrac{q}{c}\vec A \right)\right] -q\partial_i\phi=$

$ \partial_i\left[\frac{-1}{2m} \sum_j\left( p^j- \dfrac{q}{c} A^j\right)^2\right] -q\partial_i\phi=$

$ \frac{-1}{2m} \sum_j\partial_i\left[\left( p^j- \dfrac{q}{c} A^j\right)^2\right] -q\partial_i\phi=$

Then use the chain rule (for scalars)

$ \frac{-1}{2m} \sum_j\left[2\left( p^j- \dfrac{q}{c} A^j\right)\partial_i\left( p^j- \dfrac{q}{c} A^j\right)\right] -q\partial_i\phi=$

$ \frac{1}{m} \sum_j\left[\left( p^j- \dfrac{q}{c} A^j\right)\partial_i\left(\dfrac{q}{c} A^j\right)\right] -q\partial_i\phi$

And at this point you can start translating back to a vector statement if you need one.

Comment: Timaeus:  Great.  Thank you.  So we end up with the
same issue  (the  $\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{2c}\vec{A}$  instead of
$\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c}\vec{A}$)  given in the book.

This site also has that:  http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph216/QMemfield_12.pdf
page 2.  They
call it  $F_i \equiv \dfrac{\partial p_i}{\partial t}$,
and they do it one dimension at a time, but they also do
not have the $\dfrac{1}{2}$.  Very strange.

Comment: @a00 The link you provide is just fine. When you actually take the gradient you get a factor of 2 from the $\vec A \cdot \vec A$ that cancels the 1/2. The only thing wrong is "$\dot{\mathbf{p}} = \dfrac{1}{m} \nabla [(\mathbf{p} - \dfrac{q}{c}\mathbf{A})
\cdot (\dfrac{q}{c}\mathbf{A})] - q \nabla \phi$
."

Comment: Okay, so you are allowed to use chain rule like this?

$\nabla [\dfrac{1}{2m}(\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A}) \cdot
                     (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})]
 - q \nabla \phi$

$= \dfrac{1}{2m} \nabla [(\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})^2]
 - q \nabla \phi$

$=
\dfrac{1}{2m} [2 (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})
[\nabla \cdot (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})]]
 - q \nabla \phi$   (chain rule)

$=\dfrac{1}{2m} [2 (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})
[(\nabla \cdot \vec{p}) - (\nabla \cdot (\dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A}))]]
 - q \nabla \phi$

Comment: $= \dfrac{1}{2m} [2 (\vec{p} - \dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A})
[0 - (\nabla \cdot (\dfrac{q}{c} \vec{A}))]]
 - q \nabla \phi$   (since they said $\nabla \cdot \vec{p} = 0$)

It seems too easy, like cheating,
when you look at if you had tried
to use  $\dfrac{1}{2} \nabla (\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{A})
= (\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{A}
+ \mathbf{A} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{A})$  instead.

Comment: Thank you VERY much, Timaeus.  I REALLY appreciate your typing
all that out.  I tried for several days to work through it
but couldn't overcome my mental block/lack of understanding.
THANK YOU.

Also,In addition to the splitting up the gradient part, I finally
understand what you mean by don't use the identity if you want
to keep the gradient in the answer.